# C - Assigning pointers to point to specific locations

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am working with linked lists and determined that it would be really beneficial to have a global variable with the address of the first "root" link in the list.

I then have several other functions that make use of this "root" link by using it as a starting reference.

How can this be done?

My attempt was (in general):

```
int rootAddress = 0;

int main(){
    //EDIT float *ptr = 5; -> my mistake there is not 'float' in my code
    int *ptr = 5;             //but I still get these warnings
    rootAddress = ptr;

    return 0;
}

int laterFunction(){
   // float *ptr = rootAddress;
    int *ptr = rootAddress;
    return 0;
}
```

Although I get two warnings:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without cast
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without cast
```

What is the proper way to do this, or what is the best way to go about saving this "root" pointer in general if this approach is not efficient?

Comment: Q: it would be really beneficial to have a global variable.  A: Sure.  That's perfectly legimate.  Q: Although I get warnings:  initialization makes pointer from integer without cast...  A: Simply declare your global to be a pointer type, not an int.

Comment: As in: int* rootAddress = NULL; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using global variables and polluting the namespace consider using a wrapper structure. You would have one structure for a linked list and another for a node, and you would pass around a pointer to the linked list structure. It would be done as follows:

```
struct linkedlist {
  struct node *front;
  int len;
};

struct node {
  int item;
  struct node *next;
};
```

... where `item` is the item you want to store in each node. You can change this to be the datatype you wish *or* use void pointers to create a generic linked list. Be sure to add a field for a free function that the client will provide if you decide to implement a generic linked list.

Comment: Where can I find some documentation on this approach because I am not quite understanding the idea here. Is this a linked list within a structure? Where the outer structure has a pointer that points to the inner? In this way, the outer structure always has a reference to the first node?

Comment: @sherrellbc, that is absolutely correct -- the `linkedlist` structure is passed around and always points to the front node. There is no C standard documentation for this as its an implementation for an abstract mathematical modelling method (however it is a common implementation of this ADT).

Comment: I like it. Thank you for this. Makes it much simpler as you always have that root reference without storing it explicitly.

Comment: @sherrellbc, I am glad that my approach sprung some ideas into your head. Be sure to communicate this to future viewers of this post. If you need any further help leave a reply and I will follow-up respectively.

Comment: If you have a variable that's reference globally, it's often best to simply make it a global variable.  There's no shame in using a global variable (where appropriate).  Just as there's no shame in using a "goto" where appropriate.  IMHO...

Comment: PS: Whichever approach you take ... be sure to allocate space for each item (e.g. "node") you're pointing to.  In a C program, you'd generally use malloc() (and need a corresponding free() when you're done with the item).  In C++, you'd generally use "new" (with a matching "delete").

Answer (score 1):

instead of `int rootAddress = 0;` make it `float *rootAddress = 0` and instead of `rootAddress = &ptr` use `rootAddress = ptr`. You are getting warnings because your types don't match.

Comment: I removed the & character - that was a mistake when I typed this question. Also, why the float data type?

Comment: just make the types the same and you'll be on your way

Comment: Oh shoot, well actually I did not mean to put float either. I can't really replace that now. In my actual code there is no 'float' but I still get these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

```
float * rootAddress = NULL;

int main(){
float *ptr = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
*ptr = 5.0;
rootAddress = ptr;

return 0;
```

}

```
int laterFunction(){
   float *ptr = rootAddress;
    return 0;
```

}

Just need to make sure that all the pointers of the same type.  Beware of forcefully casting from one type to another.

Comment: malloc returns a void pointer. Shouldn't the assignment of a float pointer to a void pointer be sufficient? Also, why the use of malloc anyway? What is the difference between explicitly allocating memory for it and not?

Comment: Depending on the compiler settings you may get warnings if you don't cast void * to float *.  ptr holds an address, malloc assigns ptr a valid address.  If you have, float * ptr = 5.  It is pointing at address of 5, which will lead to ugliness.

Comment: I never have used malloc when working generally with pointers (similar to the example of float *ptr = 5) because if malloc is explicitly called, the overhead exists for later calls for free(), right? What is the difference by calling malloc and not calling it? The program appears to work either way